# Interpretation of Scalar Product

Tags: vectors

Given I have a vector $w = (a,b)$ with scalars $a,b$.

If I calculate the scalar product of this vector with arbitrary other vectors $x$ of dimensionality $(2,1)$ such that I receive the scalar y:

$$y = wx$$

Then for all $y$, do I get on one line which goes through the origin of the coordinate system?

Thanks

Comment: please edit the question to make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: what's unclear so far? I have a fix vector w and multiply it with other vectors (scalarmultiplication), are the scalars I get as the result of this multiplication on one straight line through (0,0)?

Comment: How can scalars lie (or not lie) on a *line* through the origin $(0,0)$?

Comment: Ok, then maybe rather: Can I fit a line through the origin to the scalars?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer what I think you're asking:

Since $y$ is a scalar, every value will be on $\mathbb{R}$ and so there is trivially a line (the real line itself) that fits every value and passes through the origin.

You say vectors $x$ of dimensionality $(2,1)$, by that I assume you mean $x=(2z, z)$ for some arbitrary scalar $z$. In that case the scalar product is:

$$y = wx = (a,b)\cdot(2z,z) = 2az + bz$$

Which is $0$ if $z=0$, i.e. $x = (0,0)$.

Comment: I mean it like on this slide, page 2...sorry for the confusion  http://research.cs.tamu.edu/prism/lectures/pr/pr_l10.pdf